# upload from iPad to VPN?

Tags: vpn, ipad

#### The setup:

I'm working on an app that has to run on a tablet. One section requires that a file (typically a picture) get uploaded to a central server. No big deal, right?

#### The catch:

The tablet is hooked up to a router (actually a fanless PC) that is on a VPN. The only connection to said server is via this VPN. *In other words, the tablet itself has no connection to the VPN - only the router does.*

#### The question:

Is there a 'direct' way to upload from the tablet -> server?

Displaying the pictures will be a challenge as well. For example,

```
<img src="http://serverip/picture.jpg">
```

...isn't going to work.

Suggestions? Maybe some sort of upload->scp->server? Perhaps some routing table magic?

Comment: Indirect? Use the iCloud as a buffer and the server periodically checks for updates?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW: The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997001/setting-up-a-basic-web-proxy-in-apache). Use `mod_proxy` on the router / apache server to redirect from your VPN-less client to the VPN-only server.